# show iframe from database row in twig symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

i use TWIG from Symfony2

i got the following Text from the database:

```
<iframe src="http://xxx.example.com/embedframe/123456" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

In the TWIG i try to show this with:

```
{{ movie.iframe }}
```

When I insert the iframe direct in the twig-Code, the iframe would be shown perfect, but when i try to view this from the variable, it view only the text above.

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twig escapes every output by default. To output html you have to use the `raw` filter. But have to be sure, your database output is safe.

```
{{ movie.iframe|raw }}
```